# I have a Desktop PC with configuration described below. Is it enough to run ESRI CITYENGINE?

Tags: cityengine

Model - Dell OptiPlex 3050, Processor - 7th Gen Intel Core i3 7100, Processor Clock Speed - 3.9GHz, CPU Cache - 3MB, Chipset - Intel B250 Chipset, RAM - 4GB, RAM Type - DDR4 2400MHz, RAM Slot - 2, HDD - 1TB, HDD Type - SATA 7.2k RPM, Optical Device - DVD RW, Keyboard - USB Keyboard, Mouse - USB Mouse, Display Port - HDMI, Audio Port - Combo, USB Port - 4 x USB3.1 Gen 1, 4 x USB2.0

Comment: Do you have a graphics card? I don't think it will do very well with onboard graphics.

Comment: The CPU is probably adequate but I wouldn't consider a machine with <=4GB of RAM, no SSD, and no graphics card sufficient for any kind of 3D GIS work. Esri's system requirements for CityEngine call for 16GB RAM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because allowing it to be answered could set a precedent for others to ask if "specific configuration X" can run "software Y"

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to adequately run CityEngine based on the latest [CityEngine (2017) requirements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/latest/get-started/esri-cityengine-system-requirements.htm). At a minimum you'll need more RAM and a dedicated video card.

**CPU speed**

2 GHz dual-core CPU minimum (at least Core2 Duo compatible Intel/AMD)

**Memory/RAM**

16 GB

**Disk space**

2 GB or more

**Video/Graphics adapter**

Nvidia—GeForce 600 and later / Quadro 600 and later
AMD—Radeon HD 7000 and later
On Windows and Mac—Intel-HD 4400 and later
On Linux and Windows—use the latest available drivers (OpenGL 4.1 or later)

**Networking hardware**

A network adapter is required